# Executing query as string variable and storing in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple code that works as follows. I have a table A and I want to query it and store the result in a new table B. For simplicity assume qty and price are two of the fields of the table A. My simple sql file contains the following and works just fine.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
CREATE TABLE B AS

SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.qty >10
```

Now I want to dynamically modify the query by representing it as a string variable (say s) and updating the string s on the fly. Suppose the string variable s is originally

```
s = 'SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.qty>10'
```

we then update it on the fly by concatenating another string as follows:

```
s = 'SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.qty>10 AND A.price >30'
```

I want to execute s as a query and save the results in Table B.

I read dynamic sql related documents of postgresql and not quite sure how to achieve the above goal. I am novice and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use function/procedure (depend upon your version of PostgreSQL) and pass the query as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function like this and pass the condition as parameter:

```
create or replace function add_table_b(s text) returns int as $$

declare
rc int:=0;
query_ text:='';

begin

if(trim(s)= '') then
s='';
else
s=' where '||s;
end if;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
execute 'CREATE TABLE B AS SELECT * FROM A '|| s;
GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;

return rc;

end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

this function will return the count of rows inserted in table B.